# Android Animation When Changing Visiblity

Tags: android

Long question for probably a short answer.

I have a series of images (displayed in a grid view) that I animate using the *AnimationDrawable* class when a button is pressed.
Snippet of code for the animation;

```
AnimationDrawable mAnimation;
view.setImageDrawable(null);

Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int rand = randomGenerator.nextInt(6);

BitmapDrawable frame0 = (BitmapDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(spinImages.get(0));
BitmapDrawable frame1 = (BitmapDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(spinImages.get(1));
BitmapDrawable last = (BitmapDrawable)context.getResources().getDrawable(endImages.get(rand));

mAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();
mAnimation.isOneShot();

for (int i=0; i < spinNumber; i++) {
    mAnimation.addFrame(frame0, spinDuration);
    mAnimation.addFrame(frame1, spinDuration);
}
mAnimation.addFrame(last, spinDuration);

view.setBackgroundDrawable(mAnimation);
view.setTag(rand);

mAnimation.start();
```

There is also a spinner that will filter the images based on the selected value, setting some of them invisible (all works well upto this point).

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String[] filterOptions;
    filterOptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spn_options);

    // hide all below filter value
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    for (int i=0; i < ((ViewGroup)gridView).getChildCount(); ++i) {
        View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)gridView).getChildAt(i);
        nextChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (nextChild instanceof ImageView) {
            // get tag
            if (Integer.parseInt(nextChild.getTag().toString()) < arg2) {
                nextChild.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            nextChild.getTag();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when the spinner to show all is selected I apply `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` on the image; which makes the images re-appear but fires the animation again. I want the image to reappear showing the final state of the animation only.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have hacked a way around it by setting the image resource prior to making it invisiable.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
    String[] filterOptions;
    filterOptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spn_options);

    // hide all below filter value
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    for (int i=0; i < ((ViewGroup)gridView).getChildCount(); ++i) {
        View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)gridView).getChildAt(i);
        nextChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (nextChild instanceof ImageView) {
            // get tag
            if (Integer.parseInt(nextChild.getTag().toString()) < arg2) {
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) nextChild;
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
                iv.setTag(nextChild.getTag().toString());
                iv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            nextChild.getTag();
        }
    }
}
```

Am still welcome to other/better solutions,